# How to open activity_main.xml instead of a fragment when selecting the home button from ChipNavigationBar?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBzLEjsrfq4 where it teaches you how to open fragments when selecting the items from the ChipNavigationBar https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar My problem is that, when I select the home item, instead of opening the fragment_home.xml, I want it to open my main_activity.xml because there is where I designed my Home.

(This is my first time posting here and I'm new to java, please be patient with me)

Thank you in advanced.

This is my code on MainActivity.java

```
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int id) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.ticket:
                        fragment = new TicketFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.agregar:
                        fragment = new AgregarFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.lugares:
                        fragment = new LugaresFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.tiendas:
                        fragment = new TiendasFragment();
                        break;

                }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. **The question should be written so that it makes sense even if the links break or change.** Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I followed a tutorial where they teach you hoy to make a Navigation Bar on the bottom of the app where you have a few icons, like Home and a few others. After that they teach you how to hook those icons/items to Fragments. But I need to hook the Home item to an activity, to my main_activity. I need to know what to write on MainActivity.java so I can open the main activity when touching the Home icon.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood by your ask, you want to open the main_activity layout while clicking on the Home button from the ChipNavigationBar bottom bar.

One simple solution is, you can use the same main_acitivity layout XML in the HomeFragment.
But there is no sense if you go with main_activity xml again with HomeFragment because ideally, main_activity xml contains the fragment holder in case if it holds all fragments which use via ChipNavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was looking for. Leaving this here in case someone else needs it (even though I learned it is better to do it with fragments, I´m new to this so I´m still learning) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyGrdOqseuw